# Resharper resolved view name is not underlined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper

In my MVC project, Resharper has stopped indicating when a view is resolved.

For example, if I had `return View("EmailList", model);` in an action, EmailList would be underlined, indicating that the view was found. I could also Ctrl-Click on EmailList, and would be taken to the view.

This has stopped working. No underlines are shown now; neither in .cs nor .cshtml files. I can't figure out what I have done. I can't find any option that will enable it again.

I am using Resharper 7 with VS2012.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes clearing the Caches in Resharper resolves these problems - In Visual Studio, select: `ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`General` and click on the `Clear Caches` button.